# HTML and bindings in popovers (Angular)

Tags: angularjs, popover, ng-bootstrap

I want my popover to contain HTML, so I have tried to do it in this way:

```
<ng-template #popContent>This is a pop content</b>!</ng-template>
<ng-template #popTitle>Fancy <b>content!!</b></ng-template>
<button type="button" [ngbPopover]="popContent" [popoverTitle]="popTitle">
My button
</button>
```

But I get this error:
Can't bind to 'ngbPopover' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.

I think it should work as it is from ng-bootstrap documentation: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have malformed HTML in the first ng-template. You're missing an opening <b>.

I put this in stackblitz and it ran fine:

```
<ng-template #popContent><b>This is a pop content</b>!</ng-template>
<ng-template #popTitle>Fancy <b>content!!</b></ng-template>
<button type="button" [ngbPopover]="popContent" [popoverTitle]="popTitle">
My button
</button>
```

Update:

I've installed a completely new Angular project with
`ng new`

I've added ng-bootstrap with `ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` - this installed packages ng-bootstrap v9.1.3 and bootstrap v4.5.

I've replaced the boiler plate code in app.component.html which now looks like:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<ng-template #popContent><b>This is a pop content</b>!</ng-template>
<ng-template #popTitle>Fancy <b>content!!</b></ng-template>
<button type="button" [ngbPopover]="popContent" [popoverTitle]="popTitle">
  My button
</button>
```

This is my app.module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

So it doesn't look like anything to do with the code (once the invalid HTML is fixed).

Only the app.component.html and app.module.ts have been updated, can you share your versions of these?

Also, what versions of Angular etc are you running. Can you share package.json?

Thanks

Comment: When I say "I put this in stackblitz", I just followed the link you posted (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples) and replaced the example with yours.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. But even after adding the opening <b>, the error is still there.

Comment: Is the ng-bootstrap module properly registered in app.module?

Comment: Not sure how it is possible, but after reloading the project several times, the error disappeared (I didn't change anything). But I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Same here. Tried many different approaches, none worked until I restarted the whole project - error is gone. Most likely it was initially caused by a missing ```imports: [NgbModule]``` in app.module.ts. @abc, Thanks for the suggestion to reload the project.